# is it possible to create an SSH tunnel in Ruby or Python without creating a local port?

Tags: python, ruby, ssh-tunnel

I'm wanting to create an SSH tunnel to use for talking securely with a remote legacy application, but I don't want other local applications to be able to use it. Is this possible with Python and/or Ruby, perhaps using an in-memory handle to the tunnel that can be written to and read from like a normal socket handle?

Comment: How would your code talk to the remote application?

Comment: By controlling access to the local tunnel port you should be able to do this using `iptables`: [iptables/pf rule to only allow XY application/user?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12499/iptables-pf-rule-to-only-allow-xy-application-user)

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle, he disassembles a TCP stream.

Comment: If you don't really need the tunnel and an SSH session is enough, [`paramiko`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) is also an option for doing it programmatically in Python.

Comment: I do need it to be an SSH tunnel... I want to communicate with an application on the remote machine from an application on the local machine securely through the SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest versions of OpenSSH support the `-W` flag to connect stdio to a remote tcp port:

```
ssh ssh_host -W host:port
```

I don't know in Python or Ruby, but in Perl you can easyly use this feature with [Net::OpenSSH](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH). For instance:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
my $out = $ssh->capture({tunnel => 1,
                         stdin_data => "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n" },
                        'www.google.com', 80);

print $out;
```

Comment: This looks promising... I'll give it a go ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I no longer need to do this so I haven't been able to give it a go. However, I'm going to accept it as the answer to my question since I'm sure access to STDIN and STDOUT is possible from Ruby and Python. :)